# Read (lookup multiple criteria) records from database table, and Write to database table with matching criteria

Tags: vb.net, excel, database-design, ms-access-2010, vlookup

How do I replicate the equation below in Access Query or in VB.net code?

```
{=SUM(IF('Customer '!$G$3='Glass Fabrication'!$D$3:$G$3,IF("Hole"='Glass Fabrication'!$A$4:$A$15,'Glass Fabrication'!$D$4:$G$15)))*E3}
```

The above equation is what I use in excel to do Vlookup more than 1 value and returns a value that matches 2 criteria. (Now, this can go on forever, and have as many criteria as possible)

Now, I am working on `VB.net` to make a Quotation system with the `MS Access` `database` (.mdb).

I have a `table` that lists all products that have several identifiers with 4 different prices. For the simplicity, let's say I have 2 identifiers and 4 prices.

I have fields like `Name` `Category` as identifiers, and sample data looks like this.

`Name` `Category` `Tier 1` `Tier 2` `Tier 3` `Tier 4`

Apple...Fruit............$2..........$2...........$1.7........$1.5

Apple...Juice............$1..........$1...........$.75........$.75

Orange..Fruit.........$1.8.......$1.8.........$1.5.........$1.3

Coke...Drink............$1..........$1...........$.75........$.75

User Input = Apple , Juice , Tier 1

I can make `=Sum(If`  formula in excel to check for `Name` column to match selected value, then check the `Category` column to check the 2nd value, then check the 1st Row header for `Tier 1 value` and returns `$1`.

I am very new to Access Database, so I have a hard time how to replicate this. I have tried making a query, but it only "filters" such criteria, and doesn't return a value.

Ultimately, I would want a table/query called `Shopping Cart` that accepts user input such as "`Apple`, `Juice`, `Tier 1`" and 4th Column(read-only) would automatically calculate and find that `Price` of `$1` by looking up those 3 things.

I have set up the shopping cart table already, and it works perfectly except I don't know how to include this read-only automatically calculated/vlookup column. (I am using DataGridView in VB.net to bind to a shopping cart table that takes 3 user inputs.)

What would be the best way to do this? Make Query in Access and make it calculate in the database itself `or` VB.net to handle the calculation and write into the 4th column everytime user inputs 3 values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this SQL query in MS Access, provided your example data is saved as an Access table:

```
SELECT Table.Name, Table.Category, [Enter Tier],
     IIF([Enter Tier] = 'Tier 1', Table.[Tier 1], IIF([Enter Tier] = 'Tier 2', Table.[Tier 2], 
     IIF([Enter Tier] = 'Tier 3', Table.[Tier 3], IIF([Enter Tier] = 'Tier 4', Table.[Tier 4], Null)))) As Price
FROM Table
WHERE Table.Name = [Enter Name] AND Table.Category = [Enter Category]
```

The Enter fields will pop up for user to fill as parameter requests when you open query. It would be better to use an Access  form for user to fill unbound textboxes and command button opens query using textbox values. Form fields can replace above Enter fields.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, Parfait. Upon researching a bit more, I found a way to do this using datatable.select. What you have advised me would work on Access Forms, but I am working on VB.net for the user interface, so I had to find other ways.

Comment: Using datatable.select, I can select 1 value and return that value. To look up this particular value, I can filter out (one or more) row values, and column values by using column index as objects. and row index as objects.

Answer (score 0):

`Dim row AS DataRow = DataTable.Select("ColumnName1 = 'value3'").FirstOrDefault()
If Not row Is Nothing Then
     searchedValue = row.Item("ColumnName2") 
End If`

Here value3 is a constant value. To use objects(variables),

`Dim row AS DataRow = DataTable.Select("ColumnName1 =  '" & variable & "'").FirstOrDefault()` was used.